# Group by not working to get count of a column with other max record in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table named PublishedData, see image below

[image]

I'm trying to get the output like, below image

[image]

Comment: And your script to do this?

Comment: a little change one more column have to select

Comment: What's the rule for obtaining UpdatedContent? I've written you a query in an answer bellow. You should follow it and not expect a copy-paste solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT dt.DistrictName, ISNULL(dt.Content, 'N/A') Content, dt.UpdatedDate, mt.LastPublished, mt.Unpublished
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DistrictName ORDER BY UpdatedDate DESC, ISNULL(Content, 'zzzzz')) seq
    FROM PublishedData) dt
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DistrictName, MAX(LastPublished) LastPublished, COUNT(CASE WHEN IsPublished = 0 THEN 1 END) Unpublished
    FROM PublishedData
    GROUP BY DistrictName) mt
  ON dt.DistrictName = mt.DistrictName
WHERE
    dt.seq = 1;
```

Because I think you use an order over `UpdatedDate, Content` to gain you two first columns.

Answer (score 1):

Check out something like this (I don't have your tables, but you will get the idea where to follow with your query):

```
SELECT DirectName,
       MAX(UpdatedDate),
       MAX(LastPublished),
       (
           SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM PublishedData inr
           WHERE inr.DirectName = outr.DirectName
               AND inr.IsPublished = 0
       ) AS Unpublished
FROM PublishedData outr
GROUP BY DirectName
```

Answer (score 0):

We should required a unique identity for that required output in PublishedData Table,Because We can't get the Latest content from given Schema.

**If you want data apart  from content like DistictName,updatedDate,LastPublishedDate and count of Unpublished records ,Please use Query given below :**

```
select T1.DistrictName,T1.UpdatedDate,T1.LastPublished,T2.Unpublished from
(select DistrictName,Max(UpdateDate) as UpdatedDate,Max(LastPublished) as LastPublished  from PublishedData group by DistrictName) T1
inner join
(select DistrictName,count(IsPublished) as Unpublished from PublishedData  where isPublished=0 group by DistrictName) T2 ON T1.DistrictName=T2.DistrictName ORDER BY T2.Unpublished DESC
```